# Randomized quicksort where pivot is chosen again after partition

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, time-complexity, quicksort

I would like to come up with a recurrence for this given problem:

> Consider a variation of the randomized quicksort algorithm where the pivot is picked randomly until the array is partitioned in such a way that both the lower subarray L and the greater subarray G
>   contain 3/4 of the elements of the array. For instance, if the randomly chosen pivot
>   partitions the array in such a way that L contains 1/10 of the elements, then another
>   pivot is randomly chosen. Analyze the expected running time of this algorithm.

At first I treated this question as if it's just a regular quicksort question and came up with this recurrence where:

```
T(n) = T(3/4n) + T(n/4) + Θ(n) (where Θ(n) comes from the partition)
```

It would make sense if we had an algorithm where the split is always 1/4 : 3/4. But we are using random pivotting here and pivot changes everytime the condition for partioning is not satisfied. I know that worst-case running time for randomized quicksort is still O(n^2) but I think under these circumstances the worst case is different now (something worse than O(n^2)). Am I on the right track so far?

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity of quick sort will never go beyond `O(n^2)` unless you chose some logic which takes `O(n)` time to chose the pivot.

The best way to chose the pivot is a random element or end or first element.

Answer (score 0):

There are `n/2` bad pivots. Assuming you never select the same pivot twice (if you do, the worst case is always selecting a bad pivot, i.e. infinite time), in the worst case you'd repeat the partitioning `n/2` times, which leads to `Θ(n^2)` complexity of partitioning phase. The recurrence becomes

```
T(n) = T(n/4) + T(3n/4) + Θ(n^2)
```